# An issue about jupyter-notebook on Raspberry Pi 3 B+

Tags: jupyter-notebook

On my RP3+B (running 2019-07-10-raspbian-buster-full.img), jupyter-notebook doesn't work. It does appear in Chromium, but a command as simple as `import time` will stall.

Error message such as:

```
    [I 22:34:54.777 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (4/5), new random ports
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py", line 15, in <module>
    from ipykernel import kernelapp as app
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ipykernel/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .connect import *
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ipykernel/connect.py", line 13, in <module>
    from IPython.core.profiledir import ProfileDir
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/IPython/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from .terminal.embed import embed
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/IPython/terminal/embed.py", line 18, in <module>
    from IPython.terminal.interactiveshell import TerminalInteractiveShell
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/IPython/terminal/interactiveshell.py", line 20, in     <module>
    from prompt_toolkit.shortcuts import create_prompt_application, create_eventloop,     create_prompt_layout, create_output
ImportError: cannot import name 'create_prompt_application' from 'prompt_toolkit.shortcuts' (/    usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/prompt_toolkit/shortcuts/__init__.py)
[W 22:34:57.810 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restart failed
[W 22:34:57.811 NotebookApp] Kernel 95b57c1c-52b5-4356-b5ee-deac4b22ca19 died, removing from map.
```

repeatedly show in the shell I started jupyter-notebook.

Any idea about how to solve this issue?

Comment: Looks like it is caused by a dependency breakage. You need to make sure prompt-toolkit is installed and the version installed is supported by the version of ipython you have.

Comment: @Tom Yan: Thanks for your comment. According to the information here: https://github.com/jupyter/jupyter_console/issues/158, the command " sudo pip install 'prompt-toolkit==1.0.15'" seems solve my issue. Thanks again for your kind help!